# GAS UI Builder for GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps-script

to all
as we all know, Appscript tipicaly for Google Spreadsheet now have a UI builder, though you can compose UI with the script itself the builder is a big factor. now

GAS application is hosted in google drive and can be either share or publish as Webapp. which is great but this type of app is very limited to storing your data in a spreadsheet well, designing a good DB spreadsheet would be enough for small application but is NOT scalable for SME to Enterprise apps.

now having google app engine which have a very good and scalable platform for a webapp.

is there anyway to port the UI library capability and use it for app engine application. having GAS UI as a javascript base (client side) it could be integrated with any serverside language in GAE.

do any one have any example on this or is it now posible?

the way I see it this might be the future for GAE having a GAS as a client side library would be great?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think you should be looking the other way round. All of Apps Script's UI widgets are borrowed from GWT in GAE. In fact, the Apps Script documentation, at places suggests that we should lookup GWT documentation when this is found inadequate.

Coming to the point of the UI bilder, I'm no GAE expert, but since you get a GWT toolkit for Eclipse, you should be able to use any of Eclipse's UI creating tools ( I may be wrong here).

Comment: thanks, but isnt it that GWT for GAE is only for Java under GAE, Iam using python base GAE and GWT as far as I know is not compatible with python as GWT JSscript is compiled along for the java modules that will use it, I know there are alternative but workaround only works until so much, now if the GAS UI widgets act as a client library as I think it is coz of the way it handles request and refresh. then is it possible to have that library available so it could be use for other hosting such as GAE, Thnks

Comment: if there is a solid alternative that I can used GWT for my Python GAE, that would be great,Thnks

Answer (score 0):

GWT is compiled to javascript.  It doesn't care what the backend is.  You can use json to communicate to your python AE instance just fine I would think.   I do GWT on java AE so don't have an example of my own but here is an example of using python on AE to use App Scripts https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/appengine

Comment: Thanks, I already know the fact that GWT is client side (once it is complied), also I have knowledge on Server and Client side(jscript and jscript library) using Json,XML and AJAX. the example in the link is good also but what I want is the UI library only of that; GWT on java is well provided in app engine, but what I need to know is a GWT like library that is supported for python, not necessarily to compile with it, but a client side GWT like library that will talk to GAE by Ajax much like JqueryUI, JqGrid which I already know. Iam looking for one that is like a GWT in GAE for Java. Thnks

Comment: GWT like client side jscript library. (client side library only) that does not need to be compile(like GWT in Java). I will code the nessesary server and client-side interface through ajax. thanks again